# "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error with spdiags when creating band diagonal matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have this sample code that creates a band diagonal matrix

```
T = 6;
d1 = ones(T-2, 1);
d2 = 2*ones(T-1, 1);
d3 = 3*ones(T, 1);

f = sparse(diag(d1, -2) + diag(d2, -1) + diag(d3) + diag(d2, 1) + diag(d1, 2));
```

but I want to avoid creating the full TxT matrix, so I want to use spdiags, like this:

```
f2 = spdiags(d1, -2, T, T) + spdiags(d2, -1, T, T) + spdiags(d3, 0, T, T) + ...
    spdiags(d2, 1, T, T) + spdiags(d1, 2, T, T);
```

matlab tells me that "index exceeds matrix dimensions" and the problem comes from these commands

```
spdiags(d2, 1, T, T)
spdiags(d3, 2, T, T)
```

but these commands work normally:

```
spdiags(d1, -2, T, T)
spdiags(d2, -1, T, T)
```

What's going on here? The final matrix should look like the sparse form of this:

```
f =
     3     2     1     0     0     0
     2     3     2     1     0     0
     1     2     3     2     1     0
     0     1     2     3     2     1
     0     0     1     2     3     2
     0     0     0     1     2     3
```

Also these are *sample* matrices that Im using as examples only.

This code works too:

```
T = 6;
d1 = ones(T-2, 1);
d2 = 2*ones(T-1, 1);
d3 = 3*ones(T, 1);

f = sparse(diag(d1, -2) + diag(d2, -1) + diag(d3) + diag(d2, 1) + diag(d1, 2));

B = [[d1;0;0], [d2;0], d3, [0;d2], [0;0;d1]];
f2 = spdiags(B, -2:2, T, T);
```

Comment: @LuisMendo good catch. I should have just made an example with d1 through d5 since technically the diagonals won't be symmetric, and it led to some too-specific examples. the length is the key here, though. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) is not very clear. It looks like you need your `d` vector to be of length `T`, even if some values will be ignored (namely, the first values are ignored for positive diagonals, and the last are ignored for negative diagonals). But somehow Matlab only actually complains for positive diagonals; for negative diagonals it does accept shorter vectors.

So: use all `d` vectors of length `T`:

```
T = 6;
d1 = ones(T, 1);
d2 = 2*ones(T, 1);
d3 = 3*ones(T, 1);
f2 = spdiags(d1, -2, T, T) + spdiags(d2, -1, T, T) + spdiags(d3, 0, T, T) + ...
    spdiags(d2, 1, T, T) + spdiags(d1, 2, T, T);
```

By the way, you can build a matrix containing all `d` vectors as columns (now that they all have the same length) and call `spdiags` just once:

```
f2 = spdiags([d1 d2 d3 d2 d1], -2:2, T, T);
```

Comment: oh ok, that... makes sense, I guess. so matlab just chops off the last few values if they're outside the matrix? that explains why my edit that appends zeros to the d* matrices works just fine.

Comment: It chops the last for negative diagonals, or the first for positive diagonals. Also, see my edit to call `spdiags` just once

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for the help. as I said those are just some simple example matrices I used as an example. my actual matrices are a bit different (and cant be made by a simple call to bsxfun).

Comment: @Ben But you can still concatenate all vectors into a matrix and call `spdiags` with that matrix. Perhaps it's faster than calling it several times, each time with a vector. I've edited my answer removing `bsxfun`, as that was too specific to your example

Comment: @LuisMendo right I have to concatenate them after they're created, not when I create them (as in your edit, which is still too specific). in my actual code, they're created with the sizes I used in my question (so I can't just change it to create them with `d1 = ones(T, 1);` as you did). That works for my simple examples but it's still too specific to apply to the actual problem (hence why they're examples). Concatenation is definitely the key here.